# VBA Code stopped working after adding Microsoft Outlook Reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to run my code all of a sudden just in my computer after adding Microsoft Outlook inside VBA’s reference.

I tried in another computer and it’s running fine. Coming back to my computer, I tried removing Microsoft Outlook in references, it was still not working so I’m not too sure.

Always getting Error Code 1004.
WorksheetFunction.Match doesn’t seem to be working at all and it’s the cause of the error in debug mode.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: No posted code and "not working" as a problem description doesn't give us much information with which to make suggestions.  Please edit your post and add relevant code, along with a description of what error(s) you're getting, and on which line(s) of code.

Comment: Show us the exact references you're adding. And your code.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is built and designed to search through all of the external references before looking for built-in commands. That means that *any reference error will always first cause a failure somewhere else*.

You have a failure at *WorksheetFunction.Match*.  That means that while looking for the command "WorksheetFunction" it found a reference error *before it even got to try WorksheetFunction*.

Any code you have, including the code where you see the error, is completely irrelevant.

VBA compiles your code to an intermediate form, and caches and runs the compiled version. It should discard and recompile when you make changes, but there are bugs in the process.  If removing the broken reference doesn't fix your spreadsheet, you need to either re-create the spreadsheet, or use a VBA cleaner program to discard the cached code.